# PHP strcasecmp with empty string equals true?

Tags: php, string

Basically I have the code:

```
echo strcasecmp('hello', ' ') ? 'true' : 'false';
```

I don't quite understand, I'm expecting the result here to be false and not true because the string aren't equal...

Is there another better way to compare strings in a case INSENSITIVE way?

Comment: strcasecmp('hello', ' ') returns an integer, so as long as it is not zero you condition will be true

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcasecmp.php

> int strcasecmp ( string $str1 , string $str2 )
>
> Returns < 0 if str1 is less than str2; > 0 if str1 is greater than str2, and 0 if they are equal.

You need to do it like

```
echo strcasecmp('hello', ' ') == 0 ? 'true' : 'false';
```

Comment: @netcoder, how about `echo strcasecmp('hello', ' ') ? 'false' : 'true';` if we are obfuscating it already :)

Answer (score 3):

This should be

```
echo (strcasecmp('hello', ' ') === 0) ? 'true' : 'false';
```

The `strcasecmp` returns 0 if both strings are equal.

https://www.php.net/strcasecmp

Answer (score 1):

You're misinterpreting the results. What `strcasecmp` returns, [according to the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcasecmp.php) is a number not equal to zero if the strings are unequal, and zero if they are equal. As you know, in PHP zero corresponds to false and non-zero corresponds to true. A proper version of your test is thus

```
echo (strcasecmp('hello', ' ') === 0) ? 'true' : 'false';
```

or, alternatively,

```
echo strcasecmp('hello', ' ') ? 'false' : 'true';
```

of which I prefer the first one, being more verbose and not containing any implicit type conversions to booleans.